# Different email header images for woocommerce emails

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I am trying to show a different header image for each email that gets sent to the customer, eg. processing order.

I have tried an if statement in email-header.php and called the email template like so

```
<?php if ('class-wc-email-customer-processing-order') :?>
    <img src="#">
<?php else: ?>
    <?php
         if ( $img = get_option( 'woocommerce_email_header_image' ) ) {
             echo '<p style="margin-top:0;"><img src="' . esc_url( $img ) . '" alt="' . get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) . '" /></p>';
         }
    ?>
```

and I have also tried to make an individual email header for each email but I haven't had any luck. I know I must be close so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: The `if ('class-wc-email-customer-processing-order')` condition doesn't test anything.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - in that case how would I target the processing order email?

Comment: Usually I think everything is possible eventually, but at a quick glance (and highly jetlagged) I don't see anything about the email object being passed to the header template or to the header hook, so I don't see anything you could test for to distinguish between the emails.

Comment: Ah of course! That makes sense, would it be possible to make different header templates for each email and call that within the email template itself?

Comment: Actually looking at the email templates, there is a 2nd variable passed to the `woocommerce_email_header` hook. See: `do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ` So you could maybe conditionally remove the current header action and add a custom one.

Comment: Yep that is what I did, I removed and replaced with a custom header per email. Thanks for the help, will post solution tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully done this by taking the HTML from email-header.php and adding it into the templates and changes out the image path like this:
Step 1: In Your child theme create a folder called woocommerce and inside of that create another folder called emails.
Step 2: copy all of your emails from wp-content > plugins > woocommerce > templates > emails
Step 3: remove do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); but leave the ?> to close the php up top in your email template 
Step 4: Then add in the HTML from email-header.php and add the path of your image

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
  <title><?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ); ?></title>
 </head>
 <body <?php echo is_rtl() ? 'rightmargin' : 'leftmargin'; ?>="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">
  <div id="wrapper" dir="<?php echo is_rtl() ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'?>">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%">
    <tr>
     <td align="center" valign="top">
      <div id="template_header_image">
       <?php
        if ( $img = get_option( 'woocommerce_email_header_image' ) ) {
         echo '<p style="margin-top:0;"><img src="ADD IMAGE PATH HERE" /></p>';
        }
       ?>
      </div>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" id="template_container">
       <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
         <!-- Header -->
         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" id="template_header">
          <tr>
           <td id="header_wrapper">
            <h1><?php echo $email_heading; ?></h1>
           </td>
          </tr>
         </table>
         <!-- End Header -->
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
         <!-- Body -->
         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" id="template_body">
          <tr>
           <td valign="top" id="body_content">
            <!-- Content -->
            <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
             <tr>
              <td valign="top">
               <div id="body_content_inner">
```

Add your image in where it says ADD IMAGE PATH HERE. 
Step 5:Do this for each different template to have a custom image on each.